# postgresql - how to make query search when username is encoded with base64?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

i want to make query search for username, the username is get encoded with base64,
how i can make the query ?

i try already try this :

```
select CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8'),language from cmsusers where CONVERT_FROM like '%c%';
```

But it's show error like this :

```
LINE 1: ... 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8'),language from cmsusers where CONVERT_FR...
```

when i try this :

```
select CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8'),language from cmsusers;
```

it's work and all username get decoded and show this :

```
 convert_from | language
 --------------+----------
 admin        | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 7seven       | EN
 Alfamart     | EN
 CircleK      | EN
 Microsoft    | EN
 Toshiba      | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 ThorSHop     | EN
 Indomaret    | EN
 carrefour    | EN
 Zara         | EN
```

so, why my `convert_from` and `like` make `query` error?
any suggestion what must i do?
thanks for attention.

Comment: Why are you saving base64 encoded usernames in the database?

Comment: that's the rules in my company sir.

Comment: completely misguided rules, but I suppose you have to live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since convert_from is a function

```
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8'),language 
from cmsusers where 
CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8') like '%c%';
```

If you have an index on username, it will not be used here and this query is likely to be rather slow for a large table.

Comment: great!, thanks for your question sir. that's what totally i need!

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT_FROM` is a function, not name of field. So in your `WHERE` clause you are trying to compare function with a string, which makes no sense. SQL does not deduct parameters automatically based on how the function was previously used. So, you should either specify what you're comparing in full:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8'),
    language
FROM cmsusers
WHERE CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8') like '%c%';
```

Or add an alias for the field in your `SELECT` statement, that way you'll get the ability to refer to it in different parts of the query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(username, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8') AS decoded_name,
    language
FROM cmsusers
WHERE decoded_name like '%c%';
```

Comment: @yose if you think either answer is good, consider [accepting one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)